# How to know if type from typeSignature property refers to any of classes extending a certain class?

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a following code, which goes through class properties

```
val members = typeOf[Product].members.filterNot(_.isMethod).foreach {
  field: Symbol => {
    val t = field.typeSignature
  }
}
```

also i have an abstract class A and classes B, C, D etc
which extends it

How can i know in my loop through Product class properties if property has a type which extends A. It can be or types B, C, D and etc... or it can be Option[B], Option[C], Option[D] and etc... or List[B], List[C], List[D] and etc

I have tried inside foreach method

```
typeOf[A].contains(t)
```

but it always returns false

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `<:<` to check against `typeOf[T]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the operator `<:<` to check the type signature against `typeOf[T]`, with `T` being the type to compare with.

Comment: Thanx, but it covers a third part of problem...Any suggestions how to recognize Option[B], List[B]

Comment: Ok, i guess the same way, just compare with typeOf[Option[A]]. Thanx again